# log = console.log, throws illegal invocation error

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a javascript file, that makes a shorthand for `console.log` as,

```
var log = console.log
log("this message is logged with shortened keyword")
```

On running, it throws error as,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Jsfiddle ---- https://jsfiddle.net/w42vp7zg/

Comment: On Firefox, the error may be more descriptive: `TypeError: 'log' called on an object that does not implement interface Console.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `console.log`, the function `log` will receive `console` as the `this` value.

When you call `log` directly, the `this` value will be `undefined` in strict mode or the global object in non-strict mode.

To solve it, you can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind `console` as the `this` value of `log`:

```
var log = console.log.bind(console);
```

Comment: after learning the `apply`, `bind` functions theoretically for years, had hit upon a practical use-case.. thanks man